# rxbinding, seekbar, only one value emit

Tags: rx-java2, rx-binding

With code as follows:

```
RxSeekBar.userChanges(seekbar)
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe({
                        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "last value: $it")
                    })
```

I am trying to catch user events of value change, problem is I don't see any logs in the console - no values emitted by observable. I am quite new to rxjava so if you have any advice I would be grateful!

Comment: Could you please provide what method is this code being called from?

Comment: I was calling it in bindView of my ViewHolder